# Gocql custom marshaller

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I have a table with a tuple column that is made up of an int64 paired with a uuid:

```
CREATE TABLE ks.mytable {
    fileid    frozen <tuple <bigint, uuid>>,
    hits      counter,
    ...
```

and I can currently set the field using a cql statement like:

```
UPDATE ks.mytable hits = hits + 1 WHERE fileid=(? ?);
```

and I pass in 2 variables as arguments, an `int64` and a `gocql.UUID`.

Instead of moving 2 variables around everywhere, I want to put these in a struct, something like

```
type MyID struct {
    id  int64
    uid  gocql.UUID
}
```

then use a `Marshaller` to pass these into the `UPDATE` statement.

Is this possible?  I am not sure if I can pass in a single variable for the tuple field.  If so, how can I do this?  I can't figure out how - I was trying to mimic https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/master/marshal_test.go#L935 but I'm getting errors where I can't set the fields in the struct (`cannot refer to unexported field or method proto`)

Comment: The error you get is because you are trying to use from a different package a variable or method that is not exported (i.e. they do not start with Upper case). But beside this, I don't know cql so I can't help. Writing `Proto` instead of `proto` may or may not fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, you are getting the following error:

> cannot refer to unexported field or method proto

This means you need to export your fields inside the struct and that means beginning with a capital letter in Go. So your struct should be:

```
type MyID struct {
    Id  int64
    Uid  gocql.UUID
}
```

Then, it should work.

Comment: Yea, so I think the gocql lib needs an update in order to support this.

Comment: Um, well no :) I don't think gocql can do anything about this. This is more like Hibernate requiring your classes to have public setter and getter methods. So, _YOU_ need to make first letters of your struct fields in capital letters. Using capital letters is _THE_ way you make your struct usable by external code, and I don't think any way around this exists.